# Как изменить отступ TextView, при включенном checkbox?

Tags: java, android

Подскажите, пожалуйста, код java который изменит отступ view сверху на заданное количество dp, если пользователь нажмёт на checkbox. И соответственно чтобы view вернулось в своё прежнее положение когда checkbox будет unchecked.

```
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="форма"               
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvRecHeight" />



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        checkHeight.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                TextView tv7 = findViewById(R.id.textView7);              
                if(isChecked) {

                } else {

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделать это можно программно:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params .setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
tv7.setLayoutParams(params);
```

в поле setMargins устанавливаете нужное вам расстояние. В итоге будет так:

```
checkHeight.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                TextView tv7 = findViewById(R.id.textView7); 
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                if(isChecked) {
                   params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom); тут ставите нужное вам расстояние
                   tv7.setLayoutParams(params); 
                } else {

                   params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom); тут ваш textView возвращаете обратно на место
                   tv7.setLayoutParams(params);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: А в каком порядке отступы в setMargins()?

Comment: @Олег, обновил ответ